# XLDeploy dar file creation using windows command prompt

Tags: java, command-line, xl-deploy

Please refer the link:
https://docs.xebialabs.com/xl-deploy/how-to/create-a-deployment-package-using-the-command-line.html

Collect the EAR file and the configuration directory and store them in the directory:

cp /some/path/petclinic-1.0.ear petclinic-package

cp -r /some/path/conf petclinic-package

Now what is cp? Java command? Maven command? Windows command?

**'cp' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cp` is the Unix/Linux file copy command. The first line copies a single file. The second line with `cp -r` copies recursively: it copies the directory tree.

You can achieve the same with the windows "copy" command or by performing these steps manually in the windows explorer.